# Building snake game javascript - inserting png images instead of drawing a rectangle on canvas

Tags: javascript

I am building a snake game in javascript.

I so far have a rectangle which moves accross the screen and is controlled by the up, down, left and right keys.

This is all working fine..

However, I want to change my moving rectangle to png images instead. I am using this tutorial as a guide, but by no means copying it

https://github.com/davethesoftwaredev/SnakeGame/tree/master/5/js

he has put him images in a separate js file, then he has referenced them in the snake file and assigned them names and numbers. Should I do mine like this or should i keep it all in one file?

I want to have a few levels and collision detection and a score board. So would it be wise to do it like his?

I dont want to put my whole code on here as it is part of a university project, so I dont want it to look like it was copied from here, but here is my code for the rectangle:

```
snake.context.fillStyle = "#f00";
snake.context.fillRect(snake.xcoord, snake.ycoord, 50, 50); //Creates the rectangle
snake.context.stroke;
```

I want this to instead, show my snakehead.png image

I am extremely new to javascript. I started learning around a month ago, so please be easy on me! I dont know much of the lingo.

I am assuming I want to want to draw an image on a canvas‏ and not create a HTML image tag‏.

Please advise me if I should use the method the guy in the tutorial has used and make a whole separate js file, or should is there a different way of doing it? Bear in mind I want to have a few game levels, collision detection with the wall and piece of fruit.. And please let me know if changing the rectangle to an image will ruin the rest of my code. I am sure I will just about be able to see what else needs changing.. maybe

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Drawing an image is rather simple. First you'll want to create an image, set the source and wait for it to load:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
    // Image is ready
};
image.src = imageURL;
```

then drawing an image to canvas is as simple as calling

```
context.drawImage(image, xPosition, yPosition);
```

Example:

```js
var context = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
};
image.src = 'http://placecage.com/320/240';
```

```html
<canvas width="320" height="240"></canvas>
```

Comment: ahh amazing thank you! Thats pretty much exactly what I meant, only my image is a .png file, can I just put image.png instead or is the code slightly different for that? Thank you!

Comment: and where it says var image = new image (), would mine say var snake = new image()? I want my image to be part of the snake object, so that I can do stuff with it if thats makes sense

Comment: As long as the URL is correct, this will work. Assuming you don't want to overwrite your `snake` object, you might want to do something like `snake.image = new Image()` or anywhere else that it's convenient to store it.

Comment: ah okay that makes sense thanks!! So it is just an image saved on my computer in the file with my js file in. I dont need a URL for this then no? If I wanted to have a different image for the snake head and snake body will this still work okay?

Comment: If it's on your computer then you should just be able to set the source to `myimage.png` or whatever, as long as it's in the same directory. Just know that you may run into issues loading images from your local machine. You can load as many images as you want, just make sure to load and save them separately.

Comment: okay great thanks. Yeah they are in the same directory :) thanks

Comment: This had worked! Amazing.. it has stopped moving though and confused if I should add a new object for the snake body. or do I just add another image.. they are all in the directory already.